# No GitHub in Intellij IDEA VCS > Checkout > Menu

Tags: github, intellij-idea

One of my Intellij IDEA (Community Edition, Linux) installations (out of all my v2017.3.4 installations) is missing GitHub from its VCS > Checkout from Version Control > [types] menu. It's got CVS, Mercurial, Subversion but not GitHub. How do I get GitHub in there and use it?

[image: VCS > Checkout > menu no GitHub]

Comment: Go to `File > Settings > Plugins` and search for `GitHub` and `Git Integration` then install those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File > Settings > Plugins` and search for `GitHub` and `Git Integration` then install those. A restart might be required in order to apply the changes.

Comment: Enabling the GitHub plugin in that Settings scope automatically offered to also enable the Git Integration plugin that the GitHub plugin depended on.

Comment: Why does IDEA require logging into a GitHub account to clone projects from it? Commandline git doesn't require that.

Comment: @Matthew I am guessing it's because of Private repository I think, It requires Login credentials. But for the sake of Public repository it seems GitHub is adding unnecessary steps, for that matter you can just use the command line for the git clone.

Comment: A short disclaimer: I am not a git expert but I found a related topic to your question; see this topic [Clone GitHub repository without account?](https://superuser.com/questions/557903/clone-github-repository-without-account). Quoting from the answer: *However, the local repo will be "read-only" in the sense that **you won't be able to push your changes back to the original repo**. You will still able to modify files and commit changes locally, though.*, that probably explains the plugin behavior.