# GitHub option not available in PyCharm VCS | Checkout from Version Control

Tags: github, pycharm

I'm trying to clone a repository from GitHub to PyCharm, and so I looked up how to do that. I looked at [this website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/cloning-a-repository-from-github.html), and it told me to go to

> 1. Choose VCS | Checkout from Version Control | GitHub on the main menu. PyCharm establishes connection with GitHub using the login and password you registered. Upon establishing connection, the Select Git Hub Repository to Clone dialog box opens.
> 2. From the Repository drop-down list, select the source repository to clone the data from.

But, when I go to VCS | Checkout from Version Control, there is no GitHub, only these options: 
[image]

So I looked at this answer to [this question, which was similar but on Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203208/no-github-in-intellij-idea-vcs-checkout-menu) (I hope PyCharm and Intellij work similarly), and the answer was to

> Go to File > Settings > Plugins and search for GitHub and Git Integration then install those. A restart might be required in order to apply the changes.

(answer was written by [Enzokie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5217712/enzokie)). So I went there and those were both installed. What is wrong and why can't I clone a repository from GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub is a web-based hosting service for version control using **Git**.

I copied that from their [webpage](https://github.com/). 
The version control system you want to use is Git. And you will connect to GitHub, (which also uses Git), to clone the project you want.

So, select the *Git* option, enter the project URL and voila!

Another version control web-hosting service who also uses Git (but also Mercurial), is [Bit-Bucket](https://bitbucket.org/?aceid=&adposition=1t1&adgroup=55499725436&campaign=1407243005&creative=269999084565&device=c&keyword=bitbucket&matchtype=e&network=g&placement=&ds_kids=p33208875779&ds_e=GOOGLE&ds_eid=700000001551985&ds_e1=GOOGLE&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_NKguovU3AIVDKqaCh3-Tw1vEAAYASAAEgLPEvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) explains what Git is.

Comment: However, when I do that, it gives me this error: Repository test failed: Cannot Run Git: File not found: git.exe

Comment: Nevermind, I found out where my Git file was, and was able to directly tell PyCharm to look for that. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No problem buddy, I was going to suggest that you re-install Git